# Cannot authenticate to spring oauth authorization server with an encoded password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm learning on integrate oauth2 to our spring boot project in order to secure our APIs. Therefore I started with a basic example that read from the [spring-security-oauth2-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) that worked well, then when I try to modify the password encoder to use whatever encoder I cannot authenticate.

This is my AuthorizationServerConfiguration:

```
@Component
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

    AuthorizationServerConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()
    }

    @Override
    void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("myclient")
              //.secret("{noop}password")  <-- this works
                .secret("{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .scopes("all")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
    }

    @Override
    void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    }
}
```

When I use `{noop}password` I can successfully authenticate with curl:

```
$ curl myclient:password@localhost:8080/oauth/token?scope=all -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"access_token":"4320fa79-38c2-45b1-a788-5ea1b5ce881a","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3599,"scope":"all"}
```

But when I turn on any hashing I am not able to authenticate. I have tried this way to authenticate with curl but no luck:

```
$ curl congero:5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc@localhost:8080/oauth/token?scope=all -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
$ curl congero:{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc@localhost:8080/oauth/token?scope=all -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

Also I added to the code this snippet to generate the password to double check, which gave me a different hashing, also tested with curl and no luck either:

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder()
String encoded = passwordEncoder.encode('password')
println "PASSWORD: $encoded"

$ curl congero:91d1ee4784686a2e2a39c214f5a4b3ebb41e1206e2d1fc770d3ff146b034f8c156ea279c73aa1629@localhost:8080/oauth/token?scope=all -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
$ curl congero:{pbkdf2}91d1ee4784686a2e2a39c214f5a4b3ebb41e1206e2d1fc770d3ff146b034f8c156ea279c73aa1629@localhost:8080/oauth/token?scope=all -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I have debugged the spring source code and found that in the password encoders (Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder and also in BcryptPasswordEncoder) the password is being decode with this method:

```
private byte[] decode(String encodedBytes) {
    if(this.encodeHashAsBase64) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBytes);
    }
    return Hex.decode(encodedBytes); 
}
```

This `Hex.decode` looks the culprit to not make passwords match, which does not occur when using `{noop}`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Am I missing any important step? The documentation is not clear for me since it is not showing how to progressively customize the configuration.

Comment: How did you get the secret `{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc` ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi copied from the sample here https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format

Comment: So you can either register a `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder` ( will work only for Pbkdf2 case ) or to use the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, in both cases your need a PasswordEncoder bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you turn on hashing, it doesn't mean you need to pass the encoded password in your curl command, just pass "`password`" and spring will encode it and compare it with

```
"{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc"
```

you need to have a bean of type `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder` so spring will use during hashing and comparing

Comment: I feel so newbie about this. Thanks for the answer, this helped me understanding better. Do you know/have any documentation to learn how to configure spring-security-oauth? I would like to learn how to configure spring security and oauth together. Btw, if I want to secure the `user:password` in basic auth, I should use https, right?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza IMHO I think it's better to use Bearer based authentication instead of authenticating each time using username:password

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi I authenticate once to get the access token, then I use it as bearer

Comment: @stacker In my application admin need to login to user account and admin has the encoded password.So is there a way for admin to bypass this password encoding while login???Please help me.ie,in my app there are two way of logging one by the user which happens normally by the clear text password which uses password encoding in spring boot and the other is by the admin where hashed password is used by admin and which needs to bypass the spring boot password encoding.

Comment: @KJEjava48 there is no way to bypass this,  but still you can allow admin to access users information for his console, depends on your use case

Comment: @stacker Is there any chance by passing an extra parameter with authentication request and then by customizing spring boot authencation process based on this parameter to determine normal signin or admin signin and there by bypassing password encoder?????

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DelegatingPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html) which is

> A password encoder that delegates to another PasswordEncoder based
>   upon a prefixed identifier.
>
> **Password Storage Format**
>
> The general format for a password is: `{id}encodedPassword`
>
> Such that "id" is an identifier used to look up which PasswordEncoder
>   should be used and "encodedPassword" is the original encoded password
>   for the selected PasswordEncoder. The "id" must be at the beginning of
>   the password, start with "{" and end with "}". If the "id" cannot be
>   found, the "id" will be null. For example, the following might be a
>   list of passwords encoded using different "id". All of the original
>   passwords are "password".
>
> {bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
>   {noop}password
>   {pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc

**For the DelegatingPasswordEncoder that we constructed above:**

- The first password would have a PasswordEncoder id of "bcrypt" and encodedPassword of
  "$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG". When
  matching it would delegate to `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.
- The second would delegate to `NoOpPasswordEncoder`.
- The third password  would delegate to `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder`.

> Password Matching is done based upon the "id" and the mapping
>   of the "id" to the PasswordEncoder provided in the constructor.

So to get this to work you should declare a `PasswordEncoder` bean (and basically you can switch between password encoders with no problems, you get the migration for free on each new created user! ) :

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to configure spring correctly. However, my problem was that I wasn't able to get any token, always got authentication failures. With @stacker answer, the problem was that I actually must not use hashed password, I still have to use plain text password in basic authentication